# How to do a pull without entering the password?

Tags: git

I am typing in:

```
git pull origin master
```

But this asks me for a password. Is there no way to do something like this:

```
git pull origin master -p MYPASS
```

?

**UPDATE**

I saw that you can set the remote URL as a solution, but I dont want to do that, as anybody can then see the password.

Comment: Have you tried searching for answers on this already? I'm sure you will find one quickly.

Comment: I always use ssh keys for git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik git has no explicit password option, but there are many other solution out on the internet

- https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/08/12/git-how-to-avoid-typing-your-password-repeatedly/

I prefer using public key authentication. You can also set it up to use even no password

- http://www.git-tower.com/learn/ebook/command-line/advanced-topics/ssh-public-keys
- http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/